# can't resolve 'fs' module using twilio with angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, twilio-click-to-call

> ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve 'fs' in
>
> ```
> '/home/**/Desktop/**/***/node_modules/request/lib'
> ```
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/Twilio/lib/base/RequestClient.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
>
> > '/home/***/Desktop/***/***/node_modules/twilio/lib/base'

Answer (score 1):

`fs` is a core module of node.js and this package as seen in here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio - is a package for node - i.e for the server-side which has access to core modules. You are trying to use a core module on the client-side which doesn't have access to core modules. (it's running over the browser).

Comment: What did you try? It's not possible to use this package on the client-side.